Can i use mixins defined in a partial that is imported in the main scss file in another partial?
I have three files:

style.scss
_mixins.scss
_navigation.scss

obviously, in _mixins.scss i have my mixins defined. In style.scss i then import these mixins with @use 'mixins';. I now also have another partial called _navigation.scss that i also imported into the main scss file using @use 'navigation';. I now want to use a mixin defined in the mixins partial, in the navigation partial. But when i try to do this i get an Error: Undefined mixin.
Is what i am trying to do not possible? If so, how would i use a mixin defined in _mixins.scss in another partial?
